# Error when running nativescript-imagepicker

Tags: nativescript-plugin

I am developing a mobile app by using nativescript with angular. I want to include an image upload in my app. So, I tried by cloning git repo for nativescript-imagepicker. It is ok if I used the command `tns run`. If I used `tns run ios/android --bundle`, it gave me the following error:

[image: Error when running demo-angular for nativescript-imagepicker]

What is the solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the plugin through

```
tns plugin add nativescript-imagepicker
```

If not, try checking if you have the dependency with:

```
tns plugin list
```

if nativescript-imagepicker is not there, try reinstalling it. I got it working with app